# PHP's ctype_digit security

Tags: php

Can anything dangerous get by 'ctype_digit' ? May be hexadecimal characters like '0x' ?

My reasoning is that not much harm can be done with just number characters.

I know 'mysqli_real_escape_string' is available but thought the ctype_digit is more restrictive and is more suitable for this case.

I'm sending the values via PHP's 'file_get_contents' for the numeric ID of the visitor.

The data is going to be sent to a MySQL query.

I know 'file_get_contents' is another can of worms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctype_digit()` *only* allows `0123456789`. Anything else will return `false`. In other words,  if you only allow digits then this function will do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

`ctype_digit` is a safe function when validating data.

Just ensure that you're passing a string to it.

Older PHPs convert ints to their corresponding characters as per ascii table.

so

`ctype_digit( 48 )`  ==> `true` equivalent to `ctype_digit( "0" );

but

`ctype_digit( 1234 )` ==> `false` and this is something many would not expect (unless the documetation has been read with attention).

Actual PHP (8.1.9) has still this behaviour but raises a warning.

Future PHPs will turn the integer into string (as per PHP warning).

---

In short, ensure to pass the function a **string**